# Explanation of message ACPI PCC probe failed

Tags: 14.04

I had installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I just re-installed it using a new Live CD. But upon booting I am presented with the following message:

```
[1.013614] ACPI PCC probe failed
```

(I started seeing this message when I inserted the Live CD, even before the installation was complete.)

I want to note that in every boot the number inside the brackets changes.

I know that there are countless similar questions in this site but I choose to ask one more time because after reading all of them I still don't know if I should do something about that message or not, so please don't refer me to any of those questions.

If I re-install will I have the same message presented to me or the problem will be fixed?

Can I do something to hide it and more importantly should I?

Is this message a problem to be solved or should I continue without doing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number in brackets is the time in seconds since your computer booted, so you can expect it to change a little each time.  [The message is harmless](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.power-management.general/56400) although annoying, and it's very unfortunate IMHO that it started popping up at boot, because now every new user with a boot problem thinks this message is related to/caused by their boot problem.

So if your system is working great otherwise, ignore it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why you say that it is unfortunate? Also from what I understand no matter what I do from now on in every new Ubuntu edition that I install starting from the 14.04.03 I will have that message appeared?

Comment: As I stated, I think it's unfortunate because "because now every new user with a boot problem thinks this message is related to/caused by their boot problem."  It will probably get fixed eventually.